# How can I create a discord welcome message with the newer version for nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

This is what I have and it is not sending anything:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    const welcomeMessage = "Please welcome <@${member.id}> <a:pepesimp:881812231208181790> welcome to our ~~cult~~ club!";
    member.guild.channels.cache.get((i) => i.name === "welcome").send(welcomeMessage);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request the `GUILD_MEMBERS` when initiating your client otherwise this event will not be triggered.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS]
});
```

You also need to make sure that you have enabled it in the Discord Developer Portal.

[image]